# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel while writing the formula, its considered as string

Tags: excel, perl

I am writing the VLOOKUP formula to an excel. i tried directly writing the formula using write_formula. I used to get #VALUE! error in excel when i hit ctrl+shift+enter in excel it works fine. Also tried with store_formula & repeat formula same error.

Looks like the formula is considered as string. Is there a way to overcome this problem?
Please help!

```
my $i = 0;
foreach (@col){
my $op_mode_lookup = $worksheet1->store_formula("=VLOOKUP(B16,DB Sheet!A2:D5,".(${i}+1).",FALSE)");
.
.
.
$worksheet1->repeat_formula('B'.$row_count, $op_mode_lookup, undef);
$i++;
}
```

I tried replacing the "store_formula("=VLOOKUP(B16,DB Sheet!A2:D5,".(${i}+1).",FALSE)");" with below still the same error.

store_formula('=VLOOKUP(B16,DB Sheet!A2:D5,'.(${i}+1).',FALSE)');
store_formula('=VLOOKUP(B16,DB Sheet!A2:D5,2,FALSE)');

Is there an alternative perl module for Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, which would overcome this issue?

Comment: yes, formula is a string when passing to excel. do I get you right that you need to pass VLOOKUP as an array function? show us the code you refer to.

Comment: Thanks KazJaw for looking into it. I have added the code as per the request, could you please suggest an suggest an solution?

Comment: I have no idea about Perl but the issue seems to be in sheet name. You need to put it in single quotation marks in this way: `=VLOOKUP(B16,'DB Sheet'!A2:B4,2,False)` or try with double quotation marks. What about array function? do you need to have it an array or not?

Comment: Sheet name is not an issue, by the way i did not understand which array function which you were referring to.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter makes the function working as array in Excel...

Comment: Just noticed, even double clicking on the cell (which has formula) & enter works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. The sheet name `DB Sheet` contains a space so Excel requires that it is enclosed in single quotes when used in formulas, like this: `"=VLOOKUP(B16,'DB Sheet'!A2:D5,1,FALSE)"`.
2. You are using `store_formula()` repeatedly in a loop. This is inefficient and incorrect. The point of `store_formula()` is that the expensive formula parse is only done once and that the pre-parsed formula can then be reused via `repeat_formula()`. The is [explained at some length in the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#store_formula%28%24formula%29) and shown [in numerous examples](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_repeat.pl). You should go back and the docs carefully and then try to apply the methodology correctly or avoid using it if it isn't something that you require.
3. There is a known (but not easily fixable) bug that can affect `VLOOKUP` formulas when used from Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. A workaround is shown in the code below.

So, fixing these issues would give something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( 'demo.xls' );
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $worksheet2 = $workbook->add_worksheet('DB Sheet');

$worksheet1->write( 'B16', 1 );

for my $row ( 0 .. 7 ) {
    $worksheet2->write( $row, 0, $row );
}

my $op_mode_lookup = $worksheet1->store_formula(
                     "=VLOOKUP(B16,'DB Sheet'!A2:D5,1,FALSE)");

# Workaround for VLOOKUP bug in WriteExcel.
@$op_mode_lookup = map {s/_ref2d/_ref2dV/;$_} @$op_mode_lookup;

my @col = (0, 1, 2, 3);
my $row_count = 1;

foreach ( @col ){
    $worksheet1->repeat_formula('B' . $row_count, $op_mode_lookup, undef);
    $row_count++;
}

__END__
```

**However**, I would advise avoiding all of this `store_formula()` code and workaround and just use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) instead.

It is API compatible with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and has faster and non-buggy formula support.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it jmcnamara. Firstly i tried Sheet name with & without invert coma same result. Secondly your workaround helped me in resolving the issue. Could you please help me understand the below line.
# Workaround for VLOOKUP bug in WriteExcel.
@$op_mode_lookup = map {s/_ref2d/_ref2dV/;$_} @$op_mode_lookup;

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Firstly, Excel requires the single quotes so you should put them in. The S::WE parser silently fixes it in this case but there are other cases where it won't. Secondly, the workaround changes the class of the parsed formulas tokens. However, there isn't much point understanding it, you should just use Excel::Writer::XLSX and avoid any workarounds.